# How to filter data from user model created based on firestore database?

Tags: database, flutter, search, google-cloud-firestore

Based on the firestore database, I've created my own user model.

```
class ReceiverModel {
  
  final String id;
  final String name;
  final String contactNumber;
  final String bloodGroup;
  final String city;
  final String accepted;

  ReceiverModel({ this.id, this.name, this.contactNumber, this.bloodGroup, this.city, this.accepted });

}
```

And, in my database file I added a stream to get all the data:

```
// Receiver List from snapshot
  List<ReceiverModel> _receiverListFromSnapshot(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
    return snapshot.documents.map((doc){
      return ReceiverModel(
        id: doc.data['id'] ?? '',
        name: doc.data['name'] ?? '',
        contactNumber: doc.data['contactNumber'] ?? '',
        bloodGroup: doc.data['bloodGroup'] ?? '',
        city: doc.data['city'] ?? '',
        accepted: doc.data['accepted'] ?? '',
      );
    }).toList();
  }

  //get receiverCollection stream
  Stream<List<ReceiverModel>> get receivers {
    return receiverCollection.snapshots()
    .map(_receiverListFromSnapshot);
  }
```

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamProvider<List<ReceiverModel>>.value(
      initialData: List(),
      value: ReceiverDatabaseService().receivers,
      child: SafeArea(
```

```
class _ReceiverListState extends State<ReceiverList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final receivers = Provider.of<List<ReceiverModel>>(context);
    
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: receivers.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return ReceiverTile(receiverModel: receivers[index]);
      },
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Now the output is like this]

Then I used it to pass data through my screens, and later on I displayed all the data that came throuh the stream by a listview. Anyways, my question is, now as I'm showing all data, I want to create a search button to display any specific bloodGroups or any specific cities, not all the datas. How can I do that?

```
return StreamProvider<List<ReceiverModel>>.value(
      initialData: List(),
      value: ReceiverDatabaseService().receivers,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Firestore Query methods against a collection reference to query particular Document Records

The various options you have to query data are like `where`, `limit`, `orderBy`, etc. [API Reference](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/Query-class.html)

Edit - Takes in input whether you want to fetch all data or search it
In your case, you can change snapshots functions to something like this

```dart
  Stream<List<ReceiverModel>> fetchReceivers({String bloodGroup}) {

    var query = receiverCollection;
    if(bloodGroup!=null)
        query = query.where("bloodGroup",isEqualTo:bloodGroup);
           
    return query.snapshots().map(_receiverListFromSnapshot);
  }
```

For adding a search button with a strict search you can call the function with the typed-in value.

I hope I have solved your query. Thanks and have a good day

Comment: I added a screenshot of how my current output is being displayed now at the end of the thread. Can you please check that? Well, I believe your function will chnage all the stream. But, I want to show all data, except when someone wants to filter it by bloodGroup or city. Do I have to create another stream for that?

Comment: I tried to write a seperate function in my database file according to you, and, its giving an error under isEqualTo:

Comment: Can you share more details? Is receiverCollection a type of `CollectionReference`?

Comment: I think you made a typo, isEqualtTo. Anyways, I guess I found a solution using your piece of code, thanks a lot, it worked.

Comment: My mistake should have been ` .where("bloodGroup", isEqualTo: bloodGroup)`

Comment: Can you please help me with one more thing? I added another piece of code at the end of the thread. In the value parameter if I use, ReceiverDatabaseService().receivers, then I can show all the entries. If I use ReceiverDatabaseService().fetchReceiversBloodGroups(bloodGroup), I can show the specific bloodGroups, and if I use ReceiverDatabaseService.fetchReceiversCity(city), I can show all the specific cities. But, how can I make this dynamic? I was trying to use ternary operator but found that it only works with two items. Any idea how I can solve this?